# Labels position of xAxis in Highcharts

Tags: charts, highcharts, graphics

I have a problem highcharts with first label , if i want to move only the first one for example to the right, how i can do it?!

I think that I've tried everything, but it just move every label on the chart.

Answer (score 0):

You can change a label's position after a chart has been rendered. For example:

```
  chart: {
    events: {
      load: function() {
        const xAxis = this.xAxis[0];
        const ticks = xAxis.ticks;
        const tickPositions = xAxis.tickPositions;

        ticks[tickPositions[0]].label.attr({
          translateX: 10
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/w875gp3s/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#attr